# leetcode 349: Intersection of Two Arrays

Tags: c, algorithm

Given two arrays, write a function to compute their intersection.

Example:
Given nums1 = [1, 2, 2, 1], nums2 = [2, 2], return [2].

Note:

Each element in the result must be unique.

The result can be in any order.

---

I first use two loops to solve this problem, and the RunTime Error pops up beacuse the complexity is O(n ^ 2). Then, I look up many solutions, but none of them is written in C. However, I find a solution in C++ using hashset and this solution is O(m + n) complexity.

The solution is here:

```
public class Solution {  
    public int[] intersection(int[] nums1, int[] nums2) {  
        if(nums1.length==0||nums2.length==0)  
            return new int[0];  
        Set<Integer> result = new HashSet();  
        Set<Integer> set1 = new HashSet();  
        for(int i=0;i<nums1.length;i++){  
            set1.add(nums1[i]);  
        }  
        for(int i=0;i<nums2.length;i++){  
            if(set1.contains(nums2[i]))  
                result.add(nums2[i]);  
        }  
        int[] res = new int[result.size()];  
        int i=0;  
        Iterator iter = result.iterator();  
        while(iter.hasNext()){  
            res[i++]=(int)iter.next();  
        }  
        return res;  
    }  
}
```

I want to use hashtable in C, so I define a hashtable struct myself and write a hashFind function to find whether the value is in the hashtable. But, RunTime Error still pops up. I want to ask if the problem stems from my hashFind function? But, I think that since I define a enough large size of hashtable and the given data from leetcode is not that large, the complexity of my algorithm should be O(m + n) too.

Here is my code:

```
/**
 * Return an array of size *returnSize.
 * Note: The returned array must be malloced, assume caller calls free().
 */
#define HASHSIZE 1007

static int hashf(int key) {
    return key % HASHSIZE;
}

typedef struct listnode {
    int val;
    struct listnode *next;
} listnode;

typedef struct hashtable {
    listnode **hash;
} hashtable;

static hashtable *hashCreat(void) {
    hashtable *h;
    int i;

    if ((h = (hashtable *) malloc(sizeof(hashtable))) == NULL) return NULL;
    if ((h->hash = (listnode **) malloc(sizeof(listnode *) * HASHSIZE)) == NULL) return NULL;
    for (i = 0; i < HASHSIZE; i++)
        h->hash[i] = NULL;
    return h;
}

static void hashRelease(hashtable *h) {
    listnode *current, *tmp;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < HASHSIZE; i++) {
        current = h->hash[i];
        while (current != NULL) {
            tmp = current->next;
            free(current);
            current = tmp;
        }
    }
    free(h->hash);
    free(h);
}

static void hashInsert(hashtable *h, int key) {
    int value;
    listnode *node;
    listnode *current;

    if ((node = (listnode *) malloc(sizeof(listnode))) ==NULL) return NULL;
    value = hashf(key);
    current = h->hash[value];
    while (current != NULL) {
        if (current->val == key) return;
        current = current->next;
    }
    node->next = h->hash[value];
    h->hash[value] = node;
    node->val = key;
}

static bool hashFind(hashtable *h, int key) {
    int value;
    listnode *current;

    value = hashf(key);
    current = h->hash[value];
    while (current != NULL) {
        if (current->val = key) return 1;
        current = current->next;
    }
    return 0;
}

int* intersection(int* nums1, int nums1Size, int* nums2, int nums2Size, int* returnSize) {
    if (nums1Size == 0 || nums2Size == 0) return NULL;

    int *result;
    int i, j;
    int pos;
    hashtable *h;

    if ((result = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * *returnSize)) ==NULL) return NULL;
    h = hashCreat();
    pos = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < nums1Size; i++)
        hashInsert(h, nums1[i]);
    for (j = 0; j < nums2Size; j++)
        if (hashFind(h, nums2[j]))
            result[pos++] = nums2[j];
    hashRelease(h);
    return result;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any answer or comment.

Comment: what is your runtime error?

Comment: @KamiKaze it means my algorithm can get the right answer but cannot be done in a limited time. Since there are solutions that are O(n * log(n)) complexity, I guess my algorithm is O(n ^ 2) complexity.

Comment: I would have expected it to just run as long as needed and not throw an error. Correct me when I am wrong but afaik a runtime error has nothing to do with the time it takes to get to the solution. It means that an illegal operation was executed

Comment: By the way, the first solution posted looks like Java, not C++.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Runtime Error means your code didn't execute and exit properly during runtime. Its not about time complexity(TLE - time limit exceeded) or space complxity(MLE - memory limit exceeded). There are many reasons of runtime error. Among those, most frequent one for Leetcode problems are - `array out of bound`. May be your are trying to access some index of your container which is out of bound.

Here is the modified and Accepted solution of yours:

```
/**
 * Return an array of size *returnSize.
 * Note: The returned array must be malloced, assume caller calls free().
 */
#define HASHSIZE 1007

static int hashf(int key) {
    return key % HASHSIZE;
}

typedef struct listnode {
    int val;
    struct listnode *next;
} listnode;

typedef struct hashtable {
    listnode **hash;
} hashtable;

static hashtable *hashCreat(void) {
    hashtable *h;
    int i;

    if ((h = (hashtable *) malloc(sizeof(hashtable))) == NULL) return NULL;
    if ((h->hash = (listnode **) malloc(sizeof(listnode *) * HASHSIZE)) == NULL) return NULL;
    for (i = 0; i < HASHSIZE; i++)
        h->hash[i] = NULL;
    return h;
}

static void hashRelease(hashtable *h) {
    listnode *current, *tmp;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < HASHSIZE; i++) {
        current = h->hash[i];
        while (current != NULL) {
            tmp = current->next;
            free(current);
            current = tmp;
        }
    }
    free(h->hash);
    free(h);
}

static void hashInsert(hashtable *h, int key) {
    int value;
    listnode *node;
    listnode *current;

    // if ((node = (listnode *) malloc(sizeof(listnode))) ==NULL) return NULL;
    // Correction: You can't return NULL from a void function
    if ((node = (listnode *) malloc(sizeof(listnode))) ==NULL) return;
    value = hashf(key);
    current = h->hash[value];
    while (current != NULL) {
        if (current->val == key) return;
        current = current->next;
    }
    node->next = h->hash[value];
    h->hash[value] = node;
    node->val = key;
}

static bool hashFind(hashtable *h, int key) {
    int value;
    listnode *current;

    value = hashf(key);
    current = h->hash[value];
    while (current != NULL) {
        // if (current->val = key) return 1;
        // Correction: == instead of =
        if (current->val == key) return 1;
        current = current->next;
    }
    return 0;
}

int* intersection(int* nums1, int nums1Size, int* nums2, int nums2Size, int* returnSize) {
    if (nums1Size == 0 || nums2Size == 0) return NULL;

    int* result;
    int i, j;
    int pos;
    hashtable *h;
    // you need another hash to check if intersection array is including duplicate elements
    hashtable *h2;

    // if ((result = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * *returnSize)) ==NULL) return NULL;
    // Correction: returnSize is the size of result array you have to return. Allocate minimum of two input array length as intersection array can't be bigger than smaller array
    int minLength = (nums1Size < nums2Size ? nums1Size : nums2Size);
    if ((result = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * (minLength + 1))) ==NULL) return NULL;
    h = hashCreat();
    h2 = hashCreat();
    pos = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < nums1Size; i++)
        hashInsert(h, nums1[i]);
    for (j = 0; j < nums2Size; j++)
        if (hashFind(h, nums2[j])) {
            // check if current element is already included or not
            if(!hashFind(h2, nums2[j])) {
                result[pos++] = nums2[j];
                hashInsert(h2, nums2[j]);
            }
        }
    hashRelease(h);
    hashRelease(h2);

    *returnSize = pos; // set the result array size which will be returned to caller as pass by reference
    return result;
}
```

The fact is - you won't get the chance to implement your own hashtable in interview. So you should learn and use some high level language like C++ which has these data-structure in standard library.

Comment: Or you just switch to python or Matlab... I think he had a reason to ask for C

Comment: Thanks, I will exam my code to find if there is  any problem as you mentioned above. Since I just finish some easy questions on leetcode, I've never seen TLE and MLE before. Thanks for pointing out my problem.

Comment: @Mashiro I edited your solution in many places (both hashtable and function). Check my answer again and let me know if you don't understand anything. Currently the solution is working mostly. Except the insertion of `0` causing problem. Try to find out the `hashInsert` problem with `0`. I will edit my answer again if I can find the problem.

Comment: @Mashiro I've corrected your solution and now it got accepted :) Check my edited answer and I've pointed out your mistakes too.

Comment: @KaidulIslam Thanks a lot! Your edited code is really helpful, I think the problem is that because I dont use a h2 to record the value that is same to the value in nums1, the pos will exceed the boundary of result if there are identical values same to the value in nums1 and they are recorded twice or more times in result. Thanks again for your patience and help!